# No error is being returned, but also the function isn't executing how it is supposed to be

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp

This have this code module written in jsp which is supposed to send OTP by connecting an API url, but I am not able to figure out where the code is going wrong. No error pops but the still isn't executing either.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction()
{
    var d1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
    var d2 = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
    var d3 = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
    var d4 = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
    var smsOTP = ""+d1+d2+d3+d4;
    alert(smsOTP);
    try{
    var settings = {
          "async": true,
          "crossDomain": true,
          "url": "http://2factor.in/API/V1/293832-67745-11e5-88de-5600000c6b13/SMS/9911991199/4499",
          "method": "GET",
          "headers": {
            "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charSet=utf-8"
          },
          "data": {}
        }

        $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
          console.log(response);
        });
}
catch(err)
{
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = err.message;
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type='button' value='Send OTP' onClick='myFunction()' />
<div id="demo"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: err.message or e.message

Comment: I don't see jQuery included anywhere in your page.

Comment: I am so sorry for that silly mistake @dekts. It's now printing "'$' is undefined".

Comment: That's the issue then; you need to include jquery.js in the page. http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/

Comment: Please add JS CDN and test the code.
https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js

Comment: Yes, I am doing that right now. Sorry, I am quite a newbie to Jquery and JavaScript.

Comment: I have added the CDN, now it doesn't show any exception or error, but also doesn't work right.
alert(smsOTP) seems to popup correctly. After that nothing happens.

Comment: Thanks Guys! I did a few changes. It works!!